# Mongoose populate not populating array of ref objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two schemas - `User` and `Site`. `User` has an array of references to `Site`. I am trying to return the array of `Site`s but for some reason its returning the array containing the ObjectIds only.

UserSchema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
sites: [{ site: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Site' },
          siteRole: { type: Number } } 
       ]})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

SiteSchema

```
const SiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: { type: String },
     url: { type: String }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Site', SiteSchema)
```

I have tried two ways but both returns the same output i.e. returns the array of site ObjectIds and not the populated version

```
 // 1st try
const user = await User.findById(id)
     .populate({
            path: 'sites',
            model: 'Site',
            populate: { path: 'site', model: 'Site' }
        }).exec()

// 2nd try
const user = await User.findById(id)
    .populate('sites.site')
   .exec(function (err, site) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            if (!site) return res.json(401)
                return res.json(site)
    })
```

Both ways returns (array of site ids instead of sites):

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60476bf103016cef60b63319",
        "siteRole": 11
    }
]
```

Comment: the 2nd try in your code is working I have tried exactly what you have written. I think there might be another problem. there may be a case you do not have any sites in your sites array property as given in the result. check it in the MongoDB console or compass.

Comment: I was finally able to solve it. There was an issue while I was inserting the data. Instead of doing this: user.sites.push({ site: site._id, siteRole: 11 }) I was doing user.sites.push({ _id: site._id, siteRole: 11 }). Thanks for the help.